# How to get data by matching only by date from datetime field in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Value stored under database field datetime: 27-12-2013 11:37:00
I want to get the data by using only date(27-12-2013) cause in datepicker I am only selecting the date to get the data of that particular date. 
Is it possible? if yes please give me a little code to understand. TIA

This is the code I am using.

```
include("config.php");
$date = $_POST['date']; //date format come like 27-12-2013
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reports where datetime = '$date'"); //actual format is 27-12-2013 11:37:00
```

Comment: can you write your php call? show codes to us

Comment: check mysql `date()` function

Comment: in your query convert your date to dd-mm-yyyy format and then search

Comment: @IsmailAltunören I just added code please check

Comment: date_time  LIKE '%$date%' can we get from this?

Comment: "I have a field in database called: 27-12-2013 11:37:00". This is the worst thing I've read today :-(

Comment: then your day is worst than that..

Answer (score 3):

Use the MySQL `DATE` function.  `SELECT whatever FROM tableName WHERE DATE(dateTimeColumn) = dateGoesHere`.

More specifically, given the code sample you added:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reports where DATE(datetime) = '$date'");
```

Comment: DATE(dateTimeColumn) whate is the field name i have to use here?

Comment: date_time LIKE '%$date%' can we get from this?

Comment: It's working fine with this way like search feature. date_time LIKE '%$date%'                                                                         Anyway thanks for the time.

Comment: That implies to me that your datetime column is not actually a datetime, but a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime("2014-12-07 23:36:00"));
```